# Can I remotely control my PS3 with my laptop?

Tags: ps3, controllers

Is there any way that a laptop can be used to control a PS3?  Most of my searches have turned up articles aimed in the other direction (using a PS3 controller on a computer), but I've not found anything quite relevant to this.

I imagine it could be possible through some sort of WiFi or Ethernet application, but probably the most straightforward way would be over Bluetooth.  Is there any software that can do this?

I'm particularly looking to be able to use my laptop as a controller to navigate menus and use applications such as Netflix.

Comment: what specifically would you like to do? For example UPnP can allow you to play files from/to ps3

Answer (score 4):

The PS3 is a closed system, so it's unlikely you can do what you're asking.

However, as homebrew software becomes more available you may find something to suit your needs.

Comment: And homebrew software will be created very soon for a lot of things because the PS3's private key was cracked. So now anyone can sign their own code as being valid

Answer (score 4):

For now, if I'm not mistaken, there is only the Sony Vaio computer that has an application to the remote for PS3. There are many limitations. You can simply send messages to friends and read your file videos / audios.

Comment: Found the app, and a hack to get around the Vaio requirement.  Unfortunately, this is not quite the remote control I was looking for though.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** control your PS3 and PS4 with your laptop or PC.

The laptop doesn't have to be a certain brand. Even the Sony Vaio Remote Play software has been hacked to work on *any* Laptop. I also have this installed on my laptop currently.

There are a few projects around controllers for the [PS3](http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps3/Remote_Play) and [PS4](http://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/DualShock_4#Projects). An actively maintained project for your use case is [**GIMX**](http://gimx.fr/). You will need a method of connecting, either with a compatible Bluetooth device or a USB dongle you will have to [make yourself](http://gimx.fr/wiki/index.php?title=DIY_USB_adapter_for_dummies). If you want to do this wireless with Bluetooth you will need Linux/Ubuntu, because the Windows Bluetooth stack allows only for [limited access and functionality](http://gimx.fr/wiki/index.php?title=FAQ#Why_isn.27t_there_a_bluetooth_version_for_windows.3F). You will find all you need to know on the project website and wiki.

It does work! I have used it… about 20 minutes before posting.

Comment: What do you mean "USB dongle you will have to make yourself"? I'm pretty sure pre-fabricated USB cables are available for just about any USB-to-USB connection you might possibly need to make.

Comment: @Iszi I updated the answer and added a link to the corresponding wiki page. They use a USB development board like Teensy, load a certain firmware onto it. Additionally they need to pass through the authentication of the DS4 controller to make other controllers work on the PS4. I just found this yesterday and haven't tinkered much with electronics, but it looks intriguing to me.